# Creating a file which links to a Website in Python

Tags: python-2.7, hyperlink

im working on a python script which has to create a file, which should be, in the best case, when double-clicked open for example IE and then load this website. I have already searched through SO and Google but i didn't find something. Do you guys have any ideas how i could realize that?

So far

Comment: You could make your 'file' a shell/bash script that when run/clicked opens a browser

Comment: this way of solving it is on hold, i don't want another script if i can avoid it

Comment: Then could you just have the script output a *.html file that due to extension rules would open in the users browser of choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `pip install winshell` to create a .url shortcut on your desktop using;

```
import os, winshell

desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join(desktop, "google.url")
target = "www.google.com/"
shortcut = file(path, 'w')
shortcut.write('[InternetShortcut]\n')
shortcut.write('URL=%s' % target)
shortcut.close()
```

[Using Python to Create Shortcuts](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/23/using-python-to-create-shortcuts/)