# Create a shortcut using URL with python for windows 10

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have multiple links **scraped**, and I want a code that creates a shortcut for each link and saves on the desktop. So whenever we click that link, It opens that particular URL on chrome. Can we do that using python ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Internet shortcuts are .url files; just regular files - documented over at http://www.lyberty.com/encyc/articles/tech/dot_url_format_-_an_unofficial_guide.html

Comment: I tried to create .url files, but I am getting an error. error message: The target "" of this internet shortcut is not valid.

Comment: I used this code:                                                           with open('StackOverflow.url', 'w+') as f:
    f.write("""[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to                     Stack Overflow                 
Type=Link
URL=http://stackoverflow.com/
Icon=text-html
Name[en_US]=StackOverflow
""")

Comment: That's missing newlines.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509809/creating-a-file-which-links-to-a-website-in-python). It solves both aspects of your problem:

- finding the correct desktop folder using the [winshell package](https://pypi.org/project/winshell/)
- creating the link-file (*.url) by writing a text file with the following content

  ```
    [InternetShortcut]
    URL=https://stackoverflow.com/
  ```

Note that on my machine it asked whether to open the *.url file with my default internet browser or some other program when I double-clicked it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did see the code from the link you mentioned. Whenever I run it , I am getting an error. " name file is not defined" . the error is from this line " shortcut=file(path, 'w'). [ solved it , thanks ] we should use open() ]